# Executable file says no module found even though package is installed in Conda environment

Tags: python, conda, pyinstaller

I created a Python executable file using PyInstaller in a Conda environment called `citygrows_demo`.

I ran `conda install nltk` to install this package into the environment, and when I run `conda list` I can see the `nltk` package is installed.

I then created the executable file called `common_fields_script.exe` using the command

```bash
pyinstaller "C:\Users\lakna\OneDrive\Desktop\CityGrows\common_fields\common_fields_script.py" --onefile --icon="C:\Users\lakna\OneDrive\Desktop\CityGrows\common_fields\touchscreen_book_bookmark_ebook_icon_191190.ico"
```

However, when I run this executable file it says that **there is no module named nltk**.

Why is this the case?

Comment: How are you creating the executable?

Comment: @osint_alex I ran this to create the executable `pyinstaller "C:\Users\lakna\OneDrive\Desktop\CityGrows\common_fields\common_fields_script.py" --onefile --icon="C:\Users\lakna\OneDrive\Desktop\CityGrows\common_fields\touchscreen_book_bookmark_ebook_icon_191190.ico"`

Comment: Is `pyinstaller` installed in the environment?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the virtual environment, then activate the environment using `conda activate citygrows_demo`, and then install the `conda install nltk`.

But the question is python is itself an executable and the python code is interpreted. what is the executable `common_fields_script.exe`.

If you have written a python script in `common_fields_script`, save it as `common_fields_script.py` and run it using the `python.exe` which is created inside the virtual environment, in the terminal, something similar to below:

```
(citygrows_demo) C:/<path_where_your_scirpt_is>> python common_fields_script.py
```

Comment: yes it runs fine in the terminal. But the issue is in regards to the executable file

Answer (score 0):

I think that pyinstaller is missing a module when creating the executable.

To fix this, run pyi-makespec "C:\Users\lakna\OneDrive\Desktop\CityGrows\common_fields\common_fields_script.py" and then edit which modules it imports in the spec file.

There's a good example on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099695/pyinstaller-fails-with-plotly). In short you need to manually add the absolute path to the nltk package that conda installed in the datas section of the .spec file that the above command creates.

Once you've done that, run pyinstaller common_fields_spec.spec "C:\Users\lakna\OneDrive\Desktop\CityGrows\common_fields\common_fields_script.py"

Comment: where can I find this spec file?

Comment: You need to make it with the first command - pyi-makespec "C:\Users\lakna\OneDrive\Desktop\CityGrows\common_fields\common_fields_script.py"