# Pyinstaller exe file gives 'plotly' has no attribute 'express' error

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller, exe, command-prompt

I have some code in Python (Jupyter Notebooks in my Anaconda environment). The file is called `myFile.py`:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
import plotly

DF = pd.read_csv('My CSV data file path')
myCol = DF['Temp'].value_counts(normalize = True)
fig = plotly.express.bar(myCol)
fig.show()
```

My code runs exactly as expected in python.

I used pyinstaller to successfully convert this code into an exe file (`pyinstaller myFile.py`). However, when I run the exe file, I get an error:

```
File "_plotly_utils\importers.py", line 39 in __getattr__
AttributeError: module 'plotly' has no attribute 'express'
Failed to execute script due to unhandled exception.
```

Here's what I tried:

1. I use the `--onefile` option with pyinstaller but that did not work.
2. I imported plotly.express as a hidden import but I got the same error (`pyinstaller --hidden-import plotly.express myFile.py`)
3. I copied the entire plotly package from my anaconda environment and pasted it in the same directory as `myFile.exe` but I got the same error.
4. I updated my version of plotly with the newest version using `conda update plotly`. It still didn't solve the issue.
5. I used the accepted solution posted here [pyinstaller fails with plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099695/pyinstaller-fails-with-plotly) but I still got the same error.

My version of plotly is version 5.9.0.

Comment: try: `import plotly.express as px` then `fig = px.bar(myCol)` . Because sometimes Pyinstaller struggles with dynamic imports.

Comment: @Obaskly That's actually what I had previously. I removed it because it was giving me a FileNotFoundError for a distributed.yaml file when I would run the compiled exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up resolving the issue. I just created a new anaconda environment using `conda create --name <my-env>` and then I reinstalled Pandas, plotly and pyinstaller. Using the command `pyinstaller myFile.py` ended up creating the exe. This time, running the exe gave no error/issues. I suspect the reason for the error last time was because of some dependency/library/module conflicts which prevented the exe from recognizing plotly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `pyi-makespec options myFile.py` to generate a `.spec` file. Then in `a` section you will find something like this:

```
a = Analysis(
    ['options', 'myFile.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
```

You need to add the path to `plotly` in `datas=[]`. So Activate the Anaconda environment you are using and execute this command to find the installation path of `plotly`:

`python -c "import plotly; print(plotly.__path__)"`

You will get an output like this:

`['C:\\Users\\Username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\YourEnv\\Lib\\site-packages\\plotly']`

Then insert it in `data` parameter. It should look like this:

`datas=[('C:\\Users\\Username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\YourEnv\\Lib\\site-packages\\plotly', 'plotly')],`

Save the .spec file and run the command: `pyinstaller myFile.spec`

This should solve the problem

Comment: I appreciate the response. Unfortunately, running the exe still gives the same error.

Comment: that is strange. try directly `pyinstaller --hidden-import=plotly --hidden-import=plotly.express myFile.py`. If it didn't work then run `pyinstaller --debug=all myFile.py` and update your question with the log.